# Is there any way in XQuery to get the current time in milliseconds since some Epoch?

Tags: xpath, xquery

`XQuery` offers various `date/time` functions like `current-dateTime()`, however I can't seem to find one which gives me the time in **milliseconds** since Epoch. Functions to extract hours, minutes and seconds seem to exist too individually.

What is the right way to get the Epoch time (i.e. unix time or similar) in `XQuery`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
(current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00-00:00")) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')
```

returns the number of seconds as a duration, and then divides by 1 millisecond to get the number of milliseconds as a number.

Comment: Thanks, I think there's an extra close brackets after the dateTime, and for proper execution it needs to be xs:dateTime.

Comment: Might be a good idea to consistently use either single- or double-quotation marks.  If this is used as the value of the `select` attribute of an XSLT tag then it will conflict with that attribute's quotation marks.

Comment: what is this 1970-01-01? Why are you subtracting currentTime with this?

Comment: In the Unix world the beginning of the year 1970 is referred to as "the Epoch", and that's what the question asked for.

Answer (score 5):

thank you for the tips. I modify the code for Oracle Service Bus 11g (OSB 11g) Xpath editor in case someone else needs it

```
{ (fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00-00:00")) div xdt:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S") }
```

Comment: if I use this as a unique key for a request, is there any possibility that during high load 2 requests can have same timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Additional tricks on **Aditya's answer** for OSB 11g.

There has an annoying bug on XQ Editors that will change **div** and **operator** into a , (comma).

Just put a conversion function in front of that code. such as xs:long, xs:string

ex.

```
{ xs:long((fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00-00:00")) div xdt:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001S")) }
```