# XQuery get milli-second part of current time

Tags: xquery

I am unable to get any in-built method for retrieving milli-second part of the given date-time.

Method current-dateTime() returns the full date & time along with milli-seconds, but I am looking for in-built one just to return millisecond.

In-built methods are available for [hours](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_hours-from-datetime.html), [minutes](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_minutes-from-datetime.html) and [for seconds](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_seconds-from-datetime.html) but not for milliseconds.

Please note, I do not wish to get the [unix-timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482347/is-there-any-way-in-xquery-to-get-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-since-some-ep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, such a function for getting just the milliseconds appears to be missing from XQuery, however this is most likely because if you read the spec, then seconds are modeled as a decimal rather than as two separate seconds and milliseconds components.

Another alternative to your answer is to use a regular expression:

```
replace(string($currentTime), ".*\.([0-9]*)[+\-].*", "$1")
```

Comment: thanks.. a more cleaner approach then the one I used.

Answer (score 2):

As I found no default method, I used following approach to get milliseconds

```
  let $sec := fn:seconds-from-dateTime($currentTime) 
  let $splitSeconds := fn:tokenize(fn:string($sec), '\.')
  let $seconds := $splitSeconds[1]
  let $milliSeconds := $splitSeconds[2]
```

Comment: Adam's approach has the benefit of handling time zones. To handle this possibility, you could tokenize `$milliSeconds` on `[-+]`.